# Download only new files with WinSCP

Tags: sftp, file-transfer, winscp

I am currently writing a WinSCP script whose aim is to retrieve all the files from an SFTP server and then put them on a specified location in a destination server (on which the script is located, FYI).
Is there anyone to check if a file has already been transferred on the destination server? Is it overwritten when it has? In that case, is that really a bad thing? In such a case, I guess that if the file already exists on the destination server, I would like nothing to happen. If it doesn't exist, then I'd like to proceed with the transfer.

You will find enclose the code written so far below

```
# Automatically abort script on errors
option batch abort

# Disable overwrite confirmations that conflict with the previous
option confirm off 

# Connect using a password 
open sftp://SERVER@IP_ADDRESS:PORT -privatekey="PRIVATE_KEY" -hostkey="HOSTKEY" -passive=off 

# Change remote directory
cd in
cd DIRECTORY

# Force binary mode transfer
option transfer binary

# Get ALL files from the directory specified
get /*.csv* \\DIRECTORY

# Remove all .csv files
rm /*.csv

# Exit WinSCP
bye
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help, hope it was clear enough, otherwise please let me know if I can provide you with further information

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to add [`-neweronly` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get#neweronly) to your [`get` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get):

```
get -neweronly /*.csv \\DIRECTORY
```

For very similar results, you can also use [`synchronize` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize):

```
synchronize local \\DIRECTORY / -filemask=*.csv
```

See also WinSCP article on [Downloading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file).